# Add basemap to dbeaver spatial viewer

Tags: openstreetmap, dbeaver

In various screen grabs of the dbeaver spatial view such as the blog post [Geometry viewer added to DBeaver](https://blog.rustprooflabs.com/2019/06/dbeaver-geometry-viewer) a basemap is shown for the spatial data.

How do I add a basemap to OSM?

Comment: OSM is the basemap in dbeaver. Your data needs to be in the correct projection or you need to transform the projection on the fly to view it. PostGIS (PgAdmin 4) also does this visualization.

Comment: Thankyou, what's the 'correct' projection WGS 84 / World Mercator [EPSG:9804] and how do i convert on the fly?

Comment: 4326  >> https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/6190

Answer (score 1):

With the recent updates to DBeaver CE 7.3.5 on 15th Feb 2021, there are a lot of enhancements to the spatial data, including multiple basemaps.

more here;
https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/Working-with-Spatial-GIS-data